# way to add a component in yocto, by making new package

Tags: yocto

I'm almost new to Yocto. And I want to add a component to Yocto.

If the component is just a file, and it doesn't need to be compiled, I can easily add this to Yocto.

I can add that component to `base-files`, but I want to do this by making new package, NOT by a way that dependent with `base-files`. But I don't know how to, for now.

Could you give me a good example?

Comment: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#new-recipe-writing-a-new-recipe

Answer (score 0):

you can see the recipe of base-files in `poky/meta/recipies-core/base-files`

for your issue you can create a `basefiles_%.bbappend` and copy your files to your destination folder inrfs